# XQUERY return result in format <!ELEMENT dynosaur ($dynosaurName) +>

Tags: xpath, xquery, flwor

I am using an `XQUERY FLWOR` expression into an `.xml` file:

```
for $dynosaur in doc("document.xml")//species
 let $dynosaurName := $dynosaur/text()        // keeping the dynosaurName as a variable
return $dynosaur
```

The above return results like:

```
<species age="84">Velociraptor</species>
```

**I need to format** the result to be like:

```
<!ELEMENT dynosaur (Velociraptor) +>
```

so i am trying using the below but not working...

```
return <!ELEMENT dynosaur ({$dynosaurName}) +> //here i want that format but it return error
```

---

And the **xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dinosauria>
    <group>
        <name>saurishia</name>
        <subgroups>
            <group>
                <name>theropoda</name>
                <subgroups>
                    <group>
                        <name>carnosaurs</name>
                        <speciesList>
                            <species age="74">Dyptosaurus</species>
                            <species age="170">Megalosaurus</species>
                            <species age="67">Tyrannosaurus</species>
                        </speciesList>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <name>coelurosauria</name>
                        <speciesList>
                            <species age="84">Velociraptor</species>
                            <species age="110">Deinonychus</species>
                            <species age="228">Eoraptor</species>
                        </speciesList>
                    </group>
                </subgroups>
            </group>
            <group>
                <name>sauropodomorpha</name>
                <subgroups>
                    <group>
                        <name>sauropods</name>
                        <speciesList>
                            <species age="155">Brachiosaurus</species>
                            <species age="155">Camarasaurus</species>
                        </speciesList>
                    </group>
                </subgroups>
            </group>
        </subgroups>
    </group>
    <group>
        <name>ornithishia</name>
        <subgroups></subgroups>
    </group>
</dinosauria>
```

---

**Finally:**

I can't find any way to return that type of result . I have checked a lot of links considering and this book : http://www.datypic.com/books/xquery/chapter09.html

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what is the relationship between your input and your desired result. You're apparently trying to produce output in the form of a DTD, but it's not a DTD that describes your input. So what is it? To put it another way, if the input changed, how would it affect the output?

Comment: @Michael Kay I will give another example,so have in mind only the xml of the question.Let's  say that this query will return 3 `species` as you can see them into the `xml file`.Lets say it returns `<species age="84">Velociraptor</species>` and two more . That will be the results from the `for loop`.I want for each one of this returned species to print it in this format. I mean the `result` of the `for loop` i want to return `<!ELEMENT dynosaur ($dynosaur_name)+>`. Where `$dynosaur_name` is the name of the dynosaur.

Comment: @Michael Kay What i want is generally to format the result in that way...to look like an `xml DTD`

Comment: @Michael Kay I completely reedited the question , so it is clear . I am doing experiments with `XQUERY` outputs that's why i am asking.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve and I can't help you any further.

Comment: @Michael Kay  Reedited the question so it is clear with a new example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try outputting text?

```
return concat("<!ELEMENT dynosaur (",$dynosaurName, ") +>")
```

Comment: Thank you ! Can you explain why it doesn't work without `,` and i have an error if i write `("$dynosaurName")` instead of `(",$dynosaurName, ")` A link for formatting results will be also nice :)